# IIS/ Node server issue on port 80 of EC2 instance

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, express, amazon-ec2

After server configuration, I had an IIS server listening on port 80 in my EC2 instance. I could access this from my elastic IP. 
But I turned off the IIS server hoping to launch my node server on port 80.

Now, both do not work !! My node application listens to port 80, but is not accessible from outside with the elastic IP.
And I tried to start the IIS server in IIS manager, it looks like it turns on. But it not accessible within the instance (using private IP) or from outside.

What can I do to fix it ?

Thanks

Server.js

```
/*******************************************************************************************/
/*CREATE AND START SERVER*/
/*******************************************************************************************/
var fs = require('fs');
var html = fs.readFileSync('./public/index.html');
var server=http.createServer(function(req,res){

    //res.write(html); // load the single view file (angular will handle the page changes on the front-end)
    //res.end();
    // application -------------------------------------------------------------
    app.get('*', function(req, res) {
        res.sendfile('./public/index.html'); // load the single view file (angular will handle the page changes on the front-end)
    });

});

server.listen(80,'localhost');
```

Comment: Did you attempt to access the server via ssh on the public/elastic IP or the private?

Also, IIS and Node is sort of crossing a lot of wires as far as architecture is concerned. I would obviously recommend running one or the other in the future but it sounds like you probably have two things launching a listener on port 80. Opposed to both "not working/operating" have you tried completely uninstalling Node?

Comment: I cannot establish connection through telnet. I have been using RDP.

Comment: I only want to run Node server. I was using IIS server simply to test port 80. I have no need for it.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend booting up a new instance with the same key pair and security group. Then move the Elastic IP over the the new instance.

To boot up Node JS **Assuming AWS Linux AMI** :

```
sudo yum update
sudo yum upgrade
sudo yum install gcc
yum groupinstall "Development tools"
wget -c https://nodejs.org/dist/v5.2.0/node-v5.2.0.tar.gz
#This is to download the source code.
tar -xzf node-v$ver.tar.gz
cd node-v$ver
./configure && make && sudo make install
```

Then your **app.js** :

```
var port = process.env.PORT || 80,
    http = require('http'),
    fs = require('fs'),
    html = fs.readFileSync('index.html');
var index = require('./index');

var server = http.createServer(function (req, res) {
    console.log(req.method + "sdf " + req.url + res);
    if (req.method === 'POST') {
        var body = '';

        req.on('data', function(chunk) {
            body += chunk;
        });

        req.on('end', function () {
            res.writeHead(200, 'OK', {'Content-Type': 'text/plain'});
            res.write (html);
            res.end();
        });
    } else {
        res.writeHead(200);
        res.write(html);
        res.end();
    }
});

server.listen(port);
console.log('Server running at http://127.0.0.1:' + port + '/');
```

And your **index.html** :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title></title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <p>Hello</p>
    </body>
</html>
```

Thats just for a very simple instance of Node JS

For a more robust setup, I would recommend going to EBS and booting up one of their samples. It's much easier.

Hope this helps

#### Update

Problem: User attempted to create `http` server listening on port 80 and had express format running

Solution: use *either* `http` listen to port or `express` - both simultaneously will not allow the program to run

Comment: I think the problem was with my server.js file.. I updated the code, could you please tell me if I have a http server setup or now ? because my http server code is not this elaborate.

Comment: This is my first node application and i would appreciate all the help.. Thank you.

Comment: Yup, looks normal to me, does it work? And are you using EC2 or EBS? I'll see if I can do a quick write up for you

Comment: When I tried replacing my server section with your code, it returns just the index.html and not the view of the angular application.

Comment: I am using EC2, but my code does not return a valid page.. I just added the server.. Until now, I was just using the app.get(*) section without the http server.

Comment: Also, are you using a Mac or PC? Just out of curiosity. Both platforms obviously perfectly capable but if you are using a Mac I would HIGHLY recommend a program called CodeRunner2. It can run your Node JS code to create local host listening to the port so you can test it in your browser. Its probably the best overall development program I've ever used - use it all day for everything. If you use PC, I'm sure you can do this in similar ways but I only use Mac and Ubuntu. Sometimes running this stuff on a local machine makes it easier to understand.

Comment: I use a PC that runs on windows.

Comment: Gotcha, it sounds like your server is in fact running on the correct port then. I noticed you are specifying the folder route of Express. Why don't you try limiting that down to just `('express')` also, did you try out the express generator module?

Comment: Actually this works correctly for me, so yes this seems to be good on my end. Are you still having port issues or anything?

Comment: Firstly,I used application generator to start my node project. That works real nice !!  Secondly, upon adding a http server to my code, my application does not load on the browser anymore. I updated the post with the exact piece of code i am using to start my http server

Comment: The port issue still exists with the ec2 instance. However, I think it will be solved once I create a http server listening on port 80 and not just a express() listening on port 80.

Comment: Oh! Ya I had this issue too when getting started. Express or create server, one or the other basically.

Comment: Express pops open that port listener for you. It's sort of a 'set up everything for you' kind of system.

Comment: Oh alright. then my setup was right. Thanks a ton iSkore.. I now have the following issue with my port: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34757661/is-the-ip-address-resolution-wrong-in-my-ec2-instance

Comment: @dpm You got it! I would also recommend to check these guy out: https://acloud.guru/home - I would've never gotten my certifications if it weren't for those courses. Studying for my DevOps Pro and they are really good about keeping you in the loop with their latest stuff, great about emailing and getting back too. They solidified all my readings of the AWS docs and tutorials and gave me such a better understanding.

Comment: Good resource. Thanks again.

Comment: @dpm if this question has been answered, would you mind marking it as answered so it can be closed? Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You still have the same problem as I described in [the comments here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34729330/ec2-instance-listen-to-a-specific-port).

When you do:

```
server.listen(80,'localhost')
```

You are telling the server to listen to requests ***from*** localhost, that means you are explicitly ignoring all external requests. Simply remove that argument to listen to requests from all addresses:

```
server.listen(80)
```

Comment: My issue is getting weird now. I understand what you suggested and did the same. My node server listening to port 80 can now be accessed from the instance browser with different IP's (I used private IP and 127.0.0.0). It still does not respond to the public/Elastic IP though. It gives me a timed out error.