# Is the IP address resolution wrong in my EC2 instance?

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

[image]

Hi,

The following is the result of `netstat -a -o -n` on my windows ec2 instance.

I see that port 80 is being used by different processes in both physical and foreign address. Does this mean that the NAT is not resolving the private and public IP address of the EC2 instance properly ?

What should I do to fix it ? On the private IP, port 80 is occupied by the node server while a chrome transaction is occupying port 80 on the foreign address.

Thanks.

Comment: Do you have control over that chrome transaction? I would say simply pop the chrome one on 3000 or 8080 or something. If you don't have control, you can always shoot the node JS server to 3000 or 8080

Comment: What you are describing is normal (and irrelevant).  Local port 80 and remote port 80 are in two different places.  Please describe the **problem** you are having, not your speculation as to its cause.

Comment: Yes I have control over the chrome instance. @Michael-sqlbot: My issue : what I see on port 80 of my private IP is not the same as what I see on port 80 of my Public/ Elastic IP.

Comment: "what I see" is still describing your analysis of the issue.  Please explain -- without interpretation -- what, exactly, you are trying to do, and in what way it fails: for example, "I am running a node.js server on this system but I cannot access it by the public IP address from a browser running on the same machine, I get a 'connection timed out' error when I try."

Comment: @Michael : I apologize for not conveying the issue clearly. I have a node server listening on port 80. I can access the application from a browser running on the same machine. The application cannot be reached using an Elastic IP. I get a connection time out error. I have set the security group with HTTP rule on port 80 for traffic from all sources (0.0.0.0/0).

Comment: While my instance allows a RDP connection, it restricts HTTP access. I say this because i have RDP and HTTP rules set up similarly except for the ports.

Comment: Is a Windows network?

Answer (score 0):

Try setting *DHCP Option set*.

I had a problem with it. Windows Domains Machines were not resolved. At Windows networks, with AD, you must fill your domain at DHCP Option.

Look at http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonVPC/latest/UserGuide/VPC_DHCP_Options.html

Comment: I am using the amazon provided DNS. I am not sure if I should still make those changes ?

Comment: Alright. Can you provide a sample of the DHCP settings ? I do not know what the fields require. Thanks